# PostgreSQL How to return tuple {a,b} but not tuple {b,a}?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Given a table of polygons with geometric data and using ST_INTERESECTS(), how can we return the polygons that intersect while preventing our results from being redundant?

To be clear, if we return polygon A intersects polygon B then it is redundant to also return the row polygon B intersects polygon A.

Example:

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.name 
FROM tl AS table1, tl AS table2
WHERE table1.name <> table2.name  // prevent returning A intersects A
AND ST_INTERSECTS( table1.coords, table2.coords) 
ORDER BY table1.name asc;
```

returns

```
hi hello  
peanut butter   
hello hi  
butter peanut
```

and I want

```
hi hello  
peanut butter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just decide that you **always** present the smaller value first, and use `<` instead of just `<>`

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.name 
FROM tl AS table1, tl AS table2
WHERE table1.name < table2.name -- The aforementioned assumption
AND ST_INTERSECTS( table1.coords, table2.coords) 
ORDER BY table1.name asc;
```

Comment: +1 That's the standard way. We're assuming that 'name' is the PK

Comment: Well, that was much easier than expected. Also, leonbloy, thanks for mentioning that we're assuming that 'name' is the PK. It wasn't, but I easily adjusted the query to use the PK. Will accept when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to apply DISTINCT on the result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT least(table1.name, table2.name) as name1, 
                greatest(table1.name, table2.name) as name2
FROM tl AS table1, tl AS table2
WHERE table1.name <> table2.name  -- prevent returning A intersects A
AND ST_INTERSECTS( table1.coords, table2.coords) 
ORDER BY table1.name asc;
```